# Add Authorization to table Schema

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have to configure the creation of the application schemas through code first so that they are generated with authorization to the dbo user. Currently when generating the migration script to publish, the script for the schemas is generated like this:

```sql
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'Comun') IS NULL EXEC(N'CREATE SCHEMA [Comun];'); GO
```

To prevent the DB from creating the schema with permissions for the user who launches the script, the schema should be generated like this:

```sql
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'Comun') IS NULL EXEC(N'CREATE SCHEMA [Comun] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];'); GO
```

In my table configurations i had set the scheme with:

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyType> builder)
          {
            base.Configure(builder);
            builder.ToTable("TableName","Comun");
            builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            builder.Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedNever();   
            builder.Property(t => t.Description).IsRequired().HasColumnName("Description").HasMaxLength(100).IsFixedLength(true);
          }
```

Is it possible to configure them from there?
Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to be about Entity Framework Core. I have added the general tag, please modify it to include the version of EF you are targeting.

Comment: Why not just make the migration update part of your CI/CD pipeline, and THAT user has the correct permissions?   You shouldn't be running migrations as a user against anything other than your local instance anyway !